# Connect Qt to MariaDB Database

Tags: c++, mysql, database, qt, mariadb

I am going to connect my program, which is written in Qt, to my database which is defined in MariaDB DBMS (XAMPP Software Package). So as you can see in the figure below, I have to install a MySQL connector instead of a MariaDB connector (This is what my book, Hand on-GUI programming with C++ and Qt said). [image]

I installed the latest MySQL connector from its official website and I went running my project this is the error that I faced after running this code.
[image]

The book said there is no need to worry just go copy the file "libmysql.dll" from the MySQL connector path to the execution path in Qt. The version I installed (MySQL Connector C++ 8.0), did not contain this file and I found a version (MySQL Connector C 6.1) that it does and I continued with the instructions of the book but the problem is not solved yet. I googled, checked StackOverflow questions, read articles, and search on youtube. Some of the solutions didn't work for me and others I didn't understand. Till now I just copied files such as "libmysql.dll", "qsqlmysql.dll", etc to many folders of Qt software path (and as u might guess nothing changed) and I also check the Qt website for this problem and I did not understand what should I do. I'll be very thankful to help me with this problem.

Comment: The database version used by apache isn't important as you are connecting to the database using QT. Since you are using MariaDB and not MySQL use MariaDB's [connector c](https://mariadb.com/docs/connect/programming-languages/c/install/). You need to link your program to the dll library in the MariaDB connector C package.

Comment: @danblack I am going to install it, while XAMPP and MariaDB on port 3306 are running, the installer default port is also 3306. should I change that? and how should i link my program to the MariaDB connector? Just by copying the "libmariadb.dll" to the Qt path?

Comment: Since the licensing terms of MySQL C Connector do not allow the distribution within the Qt binary packages, you have to compile the Qt MySQL driver plugin by yourself as described here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html#compile-only-a-specific-sql-driver for Qt5: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#compile-only-a-specific-sql-driver

Comment: @chehrlic The problem is when I execute the first command of this link; I got an error as this "'"cmake"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file". Although there is a file with the name "qt-cmake" in the directory but this command do not execute. Do you have any idea (I really don't understand this command and process of compiling; should I do something before doing this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had the same problem earlier. (windows)
[image]

then I found this link with debugged components.
https://github.com/thecodemonkey86/qt_mysql_driver/releases
and it worked.

[image]

I have the same server type as you, so it should work for you too. You have to put the appropriate files in the Qt folder. Only the current Qt version is important.

Put the files in these folders:

`C:\Qt\6.3.1\mingw_64\plugins\sqldrivers`

`C:\Qt\6.3.1\mingw_64\lib`

`C:\Qt\6.3.1\mingw_64\bin`

Make sure. That the database you set in Qt exists, otherwise you'll keep getting errors

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I use the MySQL connector, although my server type is MariaDB. Or does it keep showing you that you haven't installed the driver?

watch this video. from 3min - 7min
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9IBwc16-Us

maybe you just copied the files wrong or downloaded the wrong version of Qt

These files are simply pre-compiled. Otherwise you have to do it yourself, as already written above.

Comment: I chose the older version of these files. Now I choose the version that matches my version. Thanks a lot.